# Cannot connect to database, getting System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#

```
SqlConnection CON = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\\VS_project\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\myInfo.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CON.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO myInfo(Name,Address,Gender,LangKnownHindi)VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + Gender + "','" + LANG_Hin + "')", CON);
        SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        CON.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved SuccessFully!!!!!");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

    }
}
```

When I run this program I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll. Additional information: The connection
>   was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

Comment: You are keeping your Sql connection instance in the class scope and if you get any errors during ExecuteNonQuery, a messagebox is shown but the connection stays open. If you close the connection after each ExecuteNonQuery, why don't you declare the CON (what a variable name!) inside the click event?

Comment: And while doing that, please try to encapsulate it in a using statement to make sure the connection is closed. Also, you are just executing a non query,in this case an SqlDataAdapter is not required. Just create an SqlCommand and execute the non query through that instance.

Comment: When I run my program and click on submit button.It shows : Invalid Object name 'myInfo'.

Comment: Your SQL statement is not correct then. Are you sure there is a table with this name?

Comment: Ya..I had made The table myInfo...But when I run the program my database Connection is lost..Only when I run my program Near database red symbol arises..Indicating connection is lost.. am using visual studio 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Having a SQL connection object exist in a shared scope is a *famously* bad idea.  The connection should be created, used, and disposed within the scope of the operation using it.  Otherwise other code may try to use the same connection object (or even this same code more than once), leaving it in an unknown state.  Which is very likely what's happening here.

Create the connection in the method itself:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection CON = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\\VS_project\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\myInfo.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            CON.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO myInfo(Name,Address,Gender,LangKnownHindi)VALUES(@Name,@Address,@Gender,@LangKnownHindi)", CON);
            SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
            SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", textBox2.Text);
            SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Gender);
            SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LangKnownHindi", LANG_Hin);
            SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            CON.Close();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Saved SuccessFully!!!!!");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

***Important:*** Also, note that I've done a couple of things here:

1. Wrapped the `SqlConnection` object in a `using` block.  This basically creates a `try/finally` block which ensures that the connection is disposed after it's been used (by calling `Dispose()` in the `finally` block, so it only works on `IDisposable` objects).  It's important to ensure disposal of I/O resources.
2. Replaced your *SQL injection* vulnerabilities with query parameters.  You should always treat user input as parameter values, not as *executable SQL code*.

Comment: Not sure I like the comparison between `using` and `try/finally`, but the rest is spot on.

Comment: @DavidG: A `using` block is translated by the compiler into a `try/finally` block where `Dispose()` is called in the `finally`.  You don't have to like it, but that's how it works.

Comment: Well I did say I wasn't sure, but now I'm sure I like it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should connect inside the method and handle disconnecting right. The easiest way to do so is by using `using`, which also disposes your connection handles in created in the background.

Also, in this case a `SqlCommand` fits the purpose better. Be aware of SQL injection too, since you concatenate user input to your SQL statement. Use parameters instead!

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\\VS_project\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\myInfo.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO myInfo(Name,Address,Gender,LangKnownHindi)VALUES(@name, @address,@gender,@lang)", conn))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", textBox2.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", Gender);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lang", LANG_Hin);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved SuccessFully!!!!!");
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried Above same code.....But still same error is displayed...When I  click on submit button.It shows : Invalid Object name 'myInfo'. But I had created The databse

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure dat u have used correct denoations of for 'myInfo' means caps nd small letters are in right order??..it is actually having an error in finding d database vid same name..use checkpoints in visual studio to check d execution of your program from starting..if you dont knw how to use checkpoints in visual studio den jst google d same..it vil show u step by step progress of ur code and den when u find error line of code just copy paste d line in sql server..if format of query in database and parameters given by you are correct den it vil execute in database or otherwise it vil fail to execute and vil show you error in sql statement